# Canonical representation for sets in a group.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, gap

Let $G$ be a permutation group acting on a set $X$ of elements.

Is there a known group theory operation "$\mathrm{Canon}$" such that, for each pair $A, B \subseteq X$ of elements subsets, $\mathrm{Canon}(A) = \mathrm{Canon}(B)$ if and only if $A$ is in the orbit of $B$?

If yes, what is it called? Is it available in GAP?

*Note 1 about orbits of sets:* The orbit of a set of elements $A$ under $G$ is the following set of sets: $\{\{\sigma(x) : x \in A\}: \sigma \in G\}$. It describes how that set of elements, as a whole, may vary under $G$.

*Note 2 about orbits of sets:* The relation [$A$ is in the orbit of $B$] is symmetric. Furthermore, it is an equivalence relation. The power set $2^X$ is partitioned by it.

Comment: There is a total ordering on all objects in GAP, so if all else fails then you can define ${\rm Canon}(A)$ to be the least element in the orbit of $A$ under the GAP ordering.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. Your solution should work well enough in most cases (when the orbits are not too big to be enumerated).

Comment: @FxMySz My bad, I had read $\mathcal{O}(A)$ as "the set of orbits of elements of $A$", which is not what you wrote. I basically inverted the quantificators in my head.

Comment: @CaptainLama Oh, okay. I was worried about leaving that interpretation since I started writing the question, but I couldn't think of a good way to avoid allowing it. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your group is a group of permutations, acting naturally on sets of integers, the GRAPE package for GAP includes a function `SmallestImageSet` that produces the smallest image in the orbit of a set under a group.
The algorithm is described in:

> Linton, Steve
> Finding the smallest image of a set. (English) Zbl 1134.05302
> Gutierrez, Jaime (ed.), ISSAC 2004. Proceedings of the 2004 international symposium on symbolic and algebraic computation, Santander, Spain, July 4–7, 2004. New York, NY: ACM Press (ISBN 1-58113-827-X/pbk). 229-234

Comment: Thank you. Following your reference, I found this new approach that extends Linton's work: *Jefferson, Christopher, Eliza Jonauskyte, Markus Pfeiffer, and Rebecca Waldecker. "Minimal and canonical images." Journal of Algebra 521 (2019): 481-506.*